# Silverlight navigation between viewmodels

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, navigation, viewmodel

I'm making a timeregistration project in Silverlight. I have 2 kinds of rights, an admin and a user. I need to send the Logged in user object from one viewmodel to another.

Has anybody any idea how you can do this? Or if there is any alternative?

Help is really needed =)

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Singleton class (or normal class registered as "singleton like" using your choosen DI container) and use that to store context.

Comment: Hmmmm I prefer using the webcontext, anybody has any experience with this?

Comment: Thats not available in silverlight. It looks like a server side asp.net class

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MVVM light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) messenger

In first view model:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<MessageWithUserObject>(new MessageWithUserObject(userObject));
```

In the second:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MessageWithUserObject>(this, msg=>{//some action});
```

Comment: MessageWithUserObject is the class with the logged in user in?

Comment: Yes, create this class and add property User into it. And you can get it in next view model from msg.User